# Central european characters in Vim and printing (PDFing) them out

Tags: vim, character-encoding, windows-xp

I'm trying to *persuade* GVim 7.3 to correctly print (`:hardcopy`) central european characters (šđčćž ŠĐČĆŽ) to PDF. Settings which I believe to be relevant

```
set encoding=utf8
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf8,cp1250,latin1
set guifont=Consolas:h9:cEASTEUROPE
set printfont=Consolas:h9:cEASTEUROPE
```

After changing the encoding to `cp1250` (and writing them again, since the change in encoding screws the up) they print out correctly.

Now, I thought utf-8 was a much bigger and more complete set than cp1250. Why after that change they correctly print out, or more importantly, why I can't use them in combination with `enc=utf-8`(which I normally use because of abundance of other characters, not normally accessible)?

[image]

[image]

---

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct 27 2010 17:59:02)
MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version with OLE support
Included patches: 1-46
Compiled by Bram@KIBAALE
Big version with GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent +clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl
+cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments +conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff +digraphs -dnd
-ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path +float +folding -footer +gettext/dyn
-hangul_input +iconv/dyn +insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap -lua +menu
 +mksession +modify_fname +mouse +mouseshape +multi_byte_ime/dyn +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg +ole -osfiletype
+path_extra +perl/dyn +persistent_undo -postscript +printer -profile +python/dyn +python3/dyn +quickfix +reltime +rightleft
+ruby/dyn +scrollbind +signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static
-tag_any_white +tcl/dyn -tgetent -termresponse +textobjects +title +toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual
+visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -xfontset -xim -xterm_save +xpm_w32
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM\gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME\_gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "$VIM\_gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME\menu.vim"
Compilation: cl -c /W3 /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32   -DFEAT_CSCOPE -DFEAT_NETBEANS_INTG   -DFEAT_XPM_W32   -DWINVE
R=0x0400 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400  /Fo.\ObjGOLYHTR/ /Ox /GL -DNDEBUG  /Zl /MT -DFEAT_OLE -DFEAT_MBYTE_IME -DDYNAMIC_IME -DFEAT_GUI_W3
2 -DDYNAMIC_ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL_DLL=\"tcl83.dll\" -DDYNAMIC_TCL_VER=\"8.3\" -DFEAT_PYTH
ON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=\"python27.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=\"python31.dll\"
-DFEAT_PERL -DDYNAMIC_PERL -DDYNAMIC_PERL_DLL=\"perl512.dll\" -DFEAT_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_VER=191 -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_DLL
=\"msvcrt-ruby191.dll\" -DFEAT_BIG /Fd.\ObjGOLYHTR/ /Zi
Linking: link /RELEASE /nologo /subsystem:windows /LTCG:STATUS oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib  comdl
g32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib /machine:i386 /nodefaultlib gdi32.lib version.lib   winspool.lib comctl32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib
 /machine:i386 /nodefaultlib libcmt.lib oleaut32.lib  user32.lib      /nodefaultlib:python27.lib /nodefaultlib:python31.lib   e:\t
cl\lib\tclstub83.lib WSock32.lib e:\xpm\lib\libXpm.lib /PDB:gvim.pdb -debug
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

---

When typed and saved with enc=utf8:

```
0000000: c5a1 2020 2020 c5a0 0d0a c491 2020 2020  ..    ......    
0000010: c490 0d0a c48d 2020 2020 c48c 0d0a c487  ......    ......
0000020: 2020 2020 c486 0d0a c5be 2020 2020 c5bd      ......    ..
0000030: 0d0a 0d0a 0d0a                           ......
```

... with enc=cp1250

```
0000000: 9a20 2020 208a 0d0a f020 2020 20d0 0d0a  .    ....    ...
0000010: e820 2020 20c8 0d0a e620 2020 20c6 0d0a  .    ....    ...
0000020: 9e20 2020 208e 0d0a 0d0a                 .    .....
```

Comment: What specific characters do you get when printing/PDFing?

Comment: Try to explicitly set printing encoding before issuing the `:hardcopy` command: `:set printencoding=utf-8`.

Comment: @ib. - I do not have 'printencoding' option available, due to +printer but -postscript. Also, I forgot to mention, what I am asking has worked on one of the older versions of Vim (6.9, 7.0 ??) with some(?) settings. Alas, lost to me.

Comment: Can you show us the output of your `:version` command?

Comment: I'd be curious to see the `xxd` versions of your sample file in its various states, i.e. when written/saved in UTF-8, when written/saved in CP1250, and after being printed to PDF.  To convert to hexdump format, do `:%!xxd` (and to convert back do `:%!xxd -r`).

Comment: @DavidPope - See edit. As far as PDF xxd, I really don't think a copy paste of that size would be welcomed here, but I would be more than happy to upload the text files somewhere should you need them.

Comment: @DavidPope - Uploaded the sample text files to http://www.filedropper.com/hr-slova (2 file rar archive, no pass)

Comment: @ldigas - Thanks, I got the files from the xxd output above.  While digging around I noticed this in `:help iconv-dynamic`:  'On MS-Windows Vim can be compiled with the |+iconv/dyn| feature.  This means Vim will search for the "iconv.dll" and "libiconv.dll" libraries.  When neither of them can be found Vim will still work but some conversions won't be possible.'  You have that option set, and while my vim doesn't, I also don't have a copy of iconv.dll on my system.  Can you check to see if you have it on your system?

Comment: @DavidPope - Glad to hear it. About that other thing (the dll's) funny you should mention them - just a few days ago I asked a question about them - in any case, they can be downloaded from the vim's download page http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc - currently I do not have them on my system (while writing all this). I tried messing with them, but noticed no difference whatsoever while having them and not having them, in any kind of encoding conversion. Check my older questions for the one regarding those two files - they will be in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [very nice thread](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Printing-with-utf-8-characters-on-Windows-td1193441.html) discussing something very close to this.  The conclusion at the end is, "it doesn't work, don't do that" -- just save the file in UTF-8 and print it with something else, e.g. notepad.

This works on my system:

```
:silent !notepad /pt "%" "PDFLite"
```

where `PDFLite` is the name of my print-to-PDF printer.

**Edit**: I'm using the "utf-8" encoding in vim.

Comment: That's not very comforting considering those are a part of my alphabet, and therefore often used. I can use cp1250, and print it out as that (works fire), but then I lack the ability to use all the "cool symbols" utf has :/ (not to mention that that screws with quite a few plugins which depend on utf8 to function properly)

Comment: This doesn't solve your issue?  It amounts to replacing your usage of `:hardcopy` with the above command, and everything works.  You get to use UTF-8.

Comment: It's merely a half solution, not only causing me to think about what PDFPrinter I have on what computer, but also all kinds of other problems which arise from the fact that utf8 is not properly implemented (syntax coloring first comes to mind). I think I'll stick to cpxxxx encoding series in the immediate future for now :/

Answer (score 0):

Install paps, it works fine through the command in vim "!paps < % > out.ps", then you can convert using ps2pdf to pdf.

If on a mac, use 'brew install paps'

Comment: Don't use ps2pdf. Instead get the latest version of paps from github/dov/paps and which supports outputting pdf directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the very same version of Vim as the OP. My magic incantation for printing that stuff is:

```
:se fenc=cp1252
:w
:e ++enc=cp1252
:se enc=cp1252
:se fenc=cp1252
:se penc=cp1252
:hardcopy
```

Use a codepage that's applicable for you.
The first three lines (i.e. the saving and reloading) may not be needed, but it should ensure the text is actually converted (instead of the buffer just being reinterpreted). AFAICT `enc` and `penc` need to be set, `fenc` is just CYA. Then use `:hardcopy` whichever way you want.

Remember to change the relevant encodings (`enc`, `fenc`) back and re-save if you prefer to store the file in some other codepage (latin1, utf-8, etc). The procedure there being `:se fenc` and `:w`. You may then possibly continue with `:e` (possibly with added `++enc=xxx`) and `:se enc=xxx` to check it out and to make sure you're working on a copy using your preferred codepage, plus another round of `:se fenc=xxx` and `:w` when you're done just to be on the safe side.

It's all a bit redundant, but that's a way to be certain Vim is on the same page with you. As you've noticed there's something funny about the codepage handling on Windows (at least WRT printing), so I don't necessarily trust it to do all the right things purely internally. I just force it to change the actual byte representation and then make sure it's using that.