# What do Vim's iconv.dll and libintl.dll "do"?

Tags: vim, windows-xp

On Vim's [download page](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) there are two extra files that can be downloaded, iconv.dll and libintl.dll, aparently having something to do with encoding issues?

Since I'm having (for a long time now) some encoding issues with Vim (innability to print Croatian characters in utf8 encoding), can someone in plain english (*for dummies*) explain, what do these two files do? Help with?

Comment: X-Y questions: _`I sometimes feel the need to sneeze even though it rains, therefore I'd like to know why Chrysler vehicles are not used in movies that feature Oprah Winfrey, at least as far as Hollywood productions go`_. (Hint: the question is hard to answer constructively, and most likely will **not** lead to a solution for your actual problem)

Comment: @sehe - No, that wasn't the case. I'm interested what do these two files do, since I cannot get any difference in Vim's behaviour, and would like for someone to provide an example. The other thing was just a sidenote. Have no idea who is Oprah Winfrey ...

Answer (score 2):

Iconv is a library that handles conversions between different character sets. Presumably vim comes with something like that built-in, but with possibility to load iconv instead, if present (there's a feature called `iconv/dyn`, so seems about right).

Libintl is gettext — it handles i18n, a.k.a. translating stuff to native languages. All those .mo files in `langs/<code>/LC_MESSAGES` contain translations which are handled by libintl. Probably, vim comes bundled with an older version.

Comment: Okey, so "for dummies" ... what can I use them for? This is all theoretical, something of it already written on the download page. What do I use those two files for in practice?

Comment: @ldigas: you don't, vim does. (Well, unless you're writing an app and need i18n/character conversion functionality, but that's outside of this question's scope.) You just put them in vim's folder.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. I see absolutely no difference in Vim's behaviour, and the files differ. So what do these two affect?

Comment: @ldigas: iconv is used for charset conversions (e.g. if you open a file in an encoding different than internal one) — I don't know exact implementation details of vim, but if iconv is only loaded dynamically, then vim probably supports a subset of iconv's supported charsets, and installing it enables you to use those. That newer libintl version is described as supporting charset conversions, so you can have translations in a different charset, which is probably not useful to you at all, unless you translate vim.

Comment: Okey, in short ... can you give one example of something that changes once I install those? I've been trying stuff out whole afternoon today, and can't see anything different than usual ... (and I use three encodings normally ...)

Comment: @ldigas: `:help charset-conversion`

Answer (score 1):

If your Vim doesn't **print**/**display** certain characters correctly (but 'has' the encoding:

```
:he encoding-values
```

and features enabled<sup>1</sup>, this is almost certainly a *font* issue. I'd look in you terminal configuration how to configure a font that supports the offending characters.

---

<sup>1</sup> Look for related features in the output of

```
:version
```

E.g.:

> VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Mar 24 2011 07:07:34)
>   Included patches: 1-35
>   Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
>   Compiled by buildd@
>   Huge version with GTK2-GNOME GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
>   **+arabic** +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent +clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments +conceal +cryptv +cscope 
>   +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff +digraphs +dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search **+farsi** +file_in_path +find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() 
>   **+gettext** **-hangul_input** **+iconv** +insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap +lua/dyn +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse +mouseshape 
>   +mouse_dec +mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm **+multi_byte** **+multi_lang** -mzscheme +netbeans_intg -osfiletype +path_extra +perl/dyn +persistent_undo 
>   +postscript +printer +profile +python/dyn +python3/dyn +quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax 
>   +tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white +tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title +toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo +vreplace 
>   +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup +X11 -xfontset +xim +xsmp_interact +xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
>   ...

Comment: It has utf8 and all of the bolded features from the list. I've tried Consolas, Courier, Courier New (WinXP platform here), nd a few other fonts - no luck. I've been having trouble with that for some years now - if you can make it work I'm giving you the largest bounty I can (or whatever)...

Comment: @ldigas it seems you need to post _what Croation characters_ aren't working and _how_ they are being handled instead. Right now the problem description is non-existent, and consists of a vague pointer only. When you add the info, I'll see what I can do

Comment: None of them are working. In any case, there were several questions opened already (just write in croatian characters) from what I see, but I opened one with this problem specifically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606209/printing-ce-croatian-characters-in-vim-to-printer-or-to-pdf

Comment: I also opened a bounty on one of my own older questions on the same topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637096/central-european-characters-in-vim-and-printing-pdfing-them-out (the new one could probably be closed as a duplicate now :/