# Printing CE / Croatian characters in Vim to printer or to PDF

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Central european characters in Vim and printing (PDFing) them out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637096/central-european-characters-in-vim-and-printing-pdfing-them-out)

My relevant _vimrc settings:

```
set encoding=utf8
set fileencoding=ucs-bom,utf8,cp1250,latin1
set guifont=Consolas:h9:cEASTEUROPE
set printfont=Consolas:h9:cEASTEUROPE
```

I can write CE / Croatian characters on screen (šđčćž ŠĐČĆŽ) but when printed out they come up looking as ... well, the closest description would be A's and E's with umlauts. In any case, they don't come out properly. Printing on the printer and to PDF's results in the same behaviour.

Does anyone know what could be the source of the problem?

I'm using the latest GVim 7.3. on Windows XP, extracted from **vim73_46rt.zip** and **gvim73_46ole.zip**.