# Vim UTF-8 encoding error on Windows

Tags: vim, unicode

I have a text file with Polish characters. As long as I do not set `:set encoding=utf-8` the characters are not displayed correctly. As soon as I set it to Unicode the characters are displayed but umlauts in error messages in Vim on the other hand are not displayed anymore.

Example:

```
E37: Kein Schreibvorgang seit der letzten <c4>nderung (erzwinge mit !)
```

Instead of the `<c4>` there should be the character `Ä` displayed. Can anybody explain me why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm experiencing similar issues (you can view some of the questions in my account info, or search for "central european characters" or "croatian characters").

Changing the `encoding` value changes the way Vim displays the characters - so, the way some of the characters are displayed is changed - that's why you're getting  characters. You could probably solve your problem of Polish characters by choosing some other encoding value (one of the cpXXXX for example instead of utf8), but then you would lose the ability to display utf8 characters which can make Vim rather pretty. At least this works for my case (Croatian).

So, either use while writing polish texts one of the cpXXXX encoding values, or stick to utf8 completely. I recommend the first one. But do not change them.

Still working on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637096/central-european-characters-in-vim-and-printing-pdfing-them-out).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I there is nothing else than to ignore that once I set the encoding to utf-8 my error messages cannot display umlauts correctly any more?

Comment: @orschiro - I wouldn't want to put you off on a wrong trail - these have been just my experiences. For now, I've settled on using cs1252 (in my case) whenever I'm writing something in Croatian, and utf8 for everything else, so that's Vim's default encoding. This enables me to display all kinds of pretty characters (for example see this http://blog.samsonis.me/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/vim-task-consolas.png). In any case, I've posted a question regarding this to several places, so if you want, and if I get an answer, I can post it here as well, if you're interested. Until then, sorry ...